Select the matching values from a comma separated value column
I have the following data:

I need to extract on a new column only the values (from the comma separated ones) which match one or more from the reference data.
I've tried Index and Match but doesn't seem to work on ranges of reference data in combination with comma separated ones.

Use TEXTJOIN,TEXTSPLIT and XLOOKUP
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,","),D:D,D:D,""))



Try using the following formula: Combination of TEXTSPLIT()+IF()+TEXTJOIN()


=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(TEXTSPLIT(A2,",")=D$2:D$7,D$2:D$7,""))


Or, Using MAP()
=MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(α, TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(TEXTSPLIT(α,",")=D2:D7,D2:D7,""))))


